# How to disable an href after one click using JQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am working on a project in Laravel-5.8,

When the user clicks on the href it posts all respondents:

Controller:

```
public function submit_all_respondents(){
     ...
  Notification::route('mail', $details['employee_respondent_email'])
                                ->notify(new \App\Notifications\RespondentSubmit($details));
  Session::flash('success', 'Email sent to respondents successfully');
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

View

```
<a href ="{{ route('post.respondent.all')}}" class="btn btn-primary float-left"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> Post All Respondents</a>
```

After just a single click, I want the href to be disabled and becomes "Processng ..." until it is done.

How do I achieve this

Comment: When the anchor tag link is clicked, you go to a new page.

Comment: Until what is done? With what is shown all that happens is you load that new route when clicking on that `<a>`.

Comment: @charlietfi - I have added the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution :

```
$(...).click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':disabled')) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
        .html('<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> Processng ...');
});
```

Comment: I used this:       <script type="text/javascript">
    $(#review_comment_btn-submit).click(function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true)
            .html('<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> Processng ...');
    });
    </script>    but didn't work   id=review_comment_btn-submit

Comment: You're missing quotes arround `#review_comment_btn-submit` in your sample.

Comment: It changes to processing...  but did not disable the href. It still allows users to be able to click

Comment: It changes to processing... but did not disable the href. It still allows users to be able to click on href

Comment: Still not disabled

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the `href` using CSS.
If you add CSS style `pointer-events: none;`, that selector won't accept any pointer events. (So same as `disabled`.)

So it's good to create a new class called `.processing` and add it to selector when the user clicks it.

```js
function processing(event) {
  event.target.className += " processing";
}
```

```css
.processing {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<a href ="#" class="btn btn-primary float-left" onclick="processing(event)"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> Post All Respondents</a>
```